# Language issues in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a language file called theme.php and in this file there is the line

```
$LANG['sources_HAVE_AN_ACCOUNT'] = "Have an account?";
```

Now in the file called votes.php i am using the code:

```
 if($r) //voting done
 {
 echo "". $LANG['sources_HAVE_AN_ACCOUNT']." <a href='../login' target='_blank'  #0087F7; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;'>".$LANG['header_LOGIN_title']."</a>";
 }
 elseif(!$r) //voting failed
 {
 $effectiveVote = getEffectiveVotes($id);
 echo $effectiveVote." ".$LANG['sources_POINTS_title'];
 }
```

to allow users to perform a vote in a specific article.

The problem is that when you click on the vote button the text “Have an account?” doesn’t appears!!

Why is this happens? Where is the problem?

Comment: Language files must be named with _lang.php check this  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: @AVM i tried to rename file to en_theme.php but i am getting the same results :( No text displays!!!

Comment: use $this->lang->line('sources_HAVE_AN_ACCOUNT'); instead of $LANG['sources_HAVE_AN_ACCOUNT'] and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to check :

- Your `theme_lang.php` file must be located into `application/language/english/`
- Add `theme` to the `$autoload['langage']` array located in `application/config/autoload.php`
- Check in application/config/config.php that your `$config['language']` is set to `english`

Then, to use the translations in your votes.php controller, use this :

```
$this->lang->line('sources_HAVE_AN_ACCOUNT');
```

You can find more info in the [Language Class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html) of Codeigniter